Why doesn't rsync peform delta transfer when copying from a disk to cloud storage?
I believe the rsync manual says that incremental file transfers are performed when transferring files across file systems. However rsync's output below shows that delta-transmission is disabled when I'm transferring files from a disk to a cloud file storage mounted on a directory. Why isn't delta-transmission enabled for this filesystem boundary crossing transfer and how can it be forced?
$ tail -f out.log
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did move
[sender] hiding directory home/user/cloudDrive because of pattern cloudDrive/
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1024 bytes, did not move
created directory /home/user/cloudDrive/folder/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file


Delta transfers are used when transferring files over the network using rsync protocol, because that's when rsync saves network bandwidth and speeds up the process.
For local file systems, there is no point in doing that, and a network file system behaves like a local file system: rsync needs to read the entire file anyway, even for a delta transfer, so it might as well do a full transfer.
If you can run rsync on the cloud service, then the rsync protocol allows you to ask the remote rsync to get the checksum of the file, and the remote rsync will read the entire file, checksum it and send the result.
